# Entity Framework return no value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

Trying to select value from a empty records:

```
 var id = (from transactions in testTransactions.Transactions
                                      orderby transactions.TransID descending select transactions.TransID).First();
```

How can I give a default value then the table is empty.

Thnak you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this using first or default if the item is not there at all it would give null

```
    var id = (from transactions in testTransactions.Transactions
                                          orderby transactions.TransID descending select transactions.TransID).FirstOrDefault();
if(id!=null)
{


}
```

Comment: @Kelvin Fixx you have to check first if the value is null like above

Answer (score 0):

If you have error before line IF than, maybe you must check you class testTransaction
and add to all filed which can be null something like this

```
public string? MyVal{get;set;}
```

But if you use EF designer they must create all types automatically and you must change something else.